# Passing params from a Google Cloud Function GET Request to BigQuery

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have successfully deployed a google cloud function that takes in parameters from a POST request.  I am now trying to change it to take in parameters from a GET request since the parameters don't contain any private data.

It seems I am correctly getting the passed in parameters, but when I then try to pass them to bigQuery it tells me I have missing parameters for my query.  I know my code is correct because if I hard code the values of the parameters it works correctly e.g.:

```
bigQuery.createQueryJob({
    query,
    params: {
    "make": "acura",
    "model": "mdx",
    "modelYear": 2005
}
}).then...
```

I also know I am getting the parameters correctly because if I change my cloud function to just return the passed in query string params, it correctly returns them (commented out lines below).  If I change the cloud function to use req.body instead of req.query and make it a POST request, it also works fine.

I'm at a loss as to why "params" is not being passed to createQueryJob correctly.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Here is the code (I had to remove the actual query for privacy reasons):

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "sample-http",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^2.0.6"
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.getRecallDataByVehicleInfo = (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );

    const params = req.query;
   // res.status(200).send("make is - " + params.make + ", model is - " + params.model + ", model year is -" + params.modelYear);
   // return;

    const bigQuery = new BigQuery();

    const query = `myQuery
        where Make = @make
        and Model = @model
        and ModelYear = @modelYear`

    bigQuery.createQueryJob({
        query,
        params
    }).then(results => {
        const job = results[0];
        return job.getQueryResults({
            autoPaginate: false,
            timeoutMs: 1000000
        }, 
        callback());
    });

    const callback = () => (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send(rows);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If you have updates to your question, you can edit it with the edit link at the bottom.  No need to add a comment.

Comment: @MykWillis Thanks for the response! i'm not sure what you mean.  You might want to refer to this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

Comment: @PaulFabbroni ah, obviously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank-you @guillaume blaquiere for the help!  I changed my code to the following and it appears to be working now:

```
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.getRecallDataByVehicleInfoTest = (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );

    const params = req.query;
    const query = `query
        where lower(Make) = @make
        and lower(Model) = @model
        and CAST(ModelYear as String) = @modelYear`

    const queryObj = {query, params};
    const options = {
        autoPaginate: false,
        timeoutMs: 1000000
    }

    const bigQuery = new BigQuery();
    bigQuery.query(queryObj, options, function(err, rows){
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send(rows);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

The issue wasn't me using an old package or me using createQueryJob instead of query.  The reason a POST would work and why hard coded params would work was because they would properly send over modelYear as a number.  But when you GET the params from the queryString modelYear comes in as a string (obviously) which blows up the bigQuery sql comparison in the whereclause.

The UI for testing cloud functions assumes a POST request and so it would tell me that I wasn't passing in the make param whereas the actual call in the browser would just error out without a helpful error message because I wasn't catching and returning the error properly because I just did a .then and not a .catch on my createQueryJob.  So I didn't know what the actual issue was.

Bottom line - both createQueryJob and query can accept params despite the documentation only showing it for query and there is no difference between GET and POST for cloud functions in terms of how they handle passing params into these functions.

Here is the code that shows createQueryJob also handles params:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/bigquery.ts#L1139

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26312706)

Comment: @camelccc - sorry, thanks, I updated it and requested to delete the other one

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the right method. Have a look to the [`createQueryJob` definition](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#createQueryJob)

There is no param, it's for creating a query as job. If you have a look to [the official (bad) example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#node.js), you have to use `query` method. Here [its definition](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/BigQuery.html#query)

*Note: Why the example is bad?*

In the official example, the param provided to the `query` method is named `option`. In the documentation of the `query` method, the first (and mandatory) param is named `query`, and you can optionally add an `option` param. So, the naming is confusing.

Comment: Hmmm, based on the documentation you're right.  However, I've always done it this way and it worked fine and it still works fine as a POST or as a  GET when I hard code the params.  I have a feeling they changed the functionality/documentation which would explain the confusing naming conventions and why my code still works (might be backwards compatible but not documented).

That being said, I changed it to use query instead of createQueryJob like you said, and it appears to be working now.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Just realized I was using a really old version in my package.json (2.0.6) and the latest is 4.7.0 so the could be part of it, although again, I am using 4.7.0 on another project and createQueryJob same as above, and it works fine as a post, so I'm not sure what's up, but I will do it this way moving forward.

Comment: Looks like google's code for createQueryJob DOES handle params even though it's not documented which would explain why my code usually works https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/bigquery.ts#L1139